# Attach a jQuery Extension containing Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a grid element that generates the following HTML:

```
<div id="grid">
    <table class="grid test" ng-controller="gridController" width="900">
        <thead>
            <tr><td class="th-break" colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Potential Customer</th>
                <th>Est. Close Date</th>
                <th>Est. Revenue</th>
                <th>Probability</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="th-break" colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="opps">
            <tr ng-repeat="obj in opps|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" style="cursor:move;">
                <td>{{obj.id}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.title}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.customer}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.closeDate}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.revenue}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.probability}}</td>
                <td>{{obj.rating}}</td>
                <td><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="delete(obj)"></i></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I created angular code that bound data to the grid and it worked perfectly.  However, it was all manual binding and I'm tidying up my code.  I want to create a jQuery extension so that I can pass in a ton of options and bind the grid using:

```
$('div#grid').bindGrid();
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

$.fn.bindGrid = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({

    }, options);

    var grid = this;
    var gridMod = angular.module('grid', ['ui.sortable']);

    gridMod.controller('gridController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.orderBy = 'title';
        $scope.reverseSort = false;

        var list = [
        { 'id': 1, 'title': 'Interested in Product Designer', 'customer': '', 'closeDate': '4/2/2013', 'revenue': '$349,383.00', 'probability': '70', 'rating': 'Hot' },
        { 'id': 2, 'title': 'Interested in Product Designer', 'customer': 'Bold Sales Accessories', 'closeDate': '6/11/2013', 'revenue': '$234,382.00', 'probability': '20', 'rating': 'Cold' },
        { 'id': 3, 'title': 'Interested in Product Designer', 'customer': 'Coho Winery', 'closeDate': '6/18/2013', 'revenue': '$182,796.00', 'probability': '50', 'rating': 'Warm' },
        { 'id': 4, 'title': 'Interested in Plotters', 'customer': 'Daring Farm', 'closeDate': '7/28/2013', 'revenue': '$685,780.00', 'probability': '50', 'rating': 'Warm' }
        ];

        $scope.opps = list;

        $scope.delete = function (item) {
            var index = $scope.opps.indexOf(item);
            $scope.opps.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $scope.sortableOptions = {
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                var newOrder = list.map(function (i) {
                    return i.id;
                }).join(', ');
                console.log(newOrder);
            }
        }
    });

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(grid, ['grid']);
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

When I run this, I get "'gridController' not a function, got undefined."  I'm sure it has something to do with scope, but not sure what's going on.  Any suggestions?

And I don't want to use a directive as I need this to be highly configurable via options passed in through jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had a typo. grrhhh, too many late nights.  I've edited the code above.

Comment: So maybe just delete the question? So it won't attract attention, since you've solved your problem and it was a typo anyway?